# Google maps marker icon not loading in AIR HTMLLoader

Tags: google-maps-api-3, air, google-maps-markers

I downloaded code to use new Google maps javascript api to use in Flash AIR application from 
http://www.technogumbo.com/2011/12/Migrating-to-Javascript-from-the-Google-Maps-API-for-Flash-Using-Adobe-AIR/index.php

For the project marker I assigned an icon image. If the html file is opened in browser the icon image is loaded. However, when the same html is loaded in AIR application via HTMLLoader the marker image is not shown.

I am using the same code downloaded from above example, just have added icon image for marker.

Comment: I got the same problem... did you resolve it?

Comment: not yet Davide, am still searching